# Read files in multiple threads with limited number of threads

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, runnable

I am trying to read files in multiple threads. I want to read them and then process the files. There are approximately 30 files with 10000 JSON records in each file. I want to limit the number of threads to 3 or 4. Following is the code:

```
public class FileByMultiThread implements RemoteAccess, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void main(String args) throws WTException, InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        System.out.println("Execution Started");
        File[] files = new File("D:\\datafiles\\").listFiles();
        List<File> fileList = Arrays.asList(files);
        SessionContext session = SessionContext.getContext();
        for (File file : fileList) {
            executor.execute(() -> new SessionThread(new FileList(file), session).start());
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        executor.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    }
}


public class FileList implements Runnable {

    File fileLoc;

    FileList(File file) {
        this.fileLoc = file;
    }

    public void run() {
        readFile(fileLoc);
    }

    private void readFile(File fileLoc2) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Thread Name is: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileLoc2);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            readBatch(br);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am running this code in a specific application. The SessionContext is to get a session in that application. Even though I limited the threads to 3 in ExecutorService, it creates about 30 threads.

```
2020-03-02 04:25:51,664 INFO  [RMI TCP Connection(33)] wt.system.out  - Execution Started
2020-03-02 04:25:51,669 INFO  [SessionThread-1]   - Thread Name is: SessionThread-1
2020-03-02 04:25:51,669 INFO  [SessionThread-3]   - Thread Name is: SessionThread-3
2020-03-02 04:25:51,674 INFO  [SessionThread-5]   - Thread Name is: SessionThread-5
2020-03-02 04:25:51,674 INFO  [SessionThread-8]   - Thread Name is: SessionThread-8
2020-03-02 04:25:51,674 INFO  [SessionThread-10]   - Thread Name is: SessionThread-10
2020-03-02 04:25:51,674 INFO  [SessionThread-4]   - Thread Name is: SessionThread-4
2020-03-02 04:25:51,674 INFO  [SessionThread-2]   - Thread Name is: SessionThread-2
2020-03-02 04:25:51,685 INFO  [SessionThread-9]   - Thread Name is: SessionThread-9
2020-03-02 04:25:51,689 INFO  [SessionThread-6]   - Thread Name is: SessionThread-6
2020-03-02 04:25:51,689 INFO  [SessionThread-21]   - Thread Name is: SessionThread-21
2020-03-02 04:25:51,694 INFO  [SessionThread-12]   - Thread Name is: SessionThread-12
2020-03-02 04:25:51,694 INFO  [SessionThread-11]   - Thread Name is: SessionThread-11
2020-03-02 04:25:51,694 INFO  [SessionThread-30]   - Thread Name is: SessionThread-30
2020-03-02 04:25:51,694 INFO  [SessionThread-16]   - Thread Name is: SessionThread-16
2020-03-02 04:25:51,699 INFO  [SessionThread-29]   - Thread Name is: SessionThread-29
2020-03-02 04:25:51,699 INFO  [SessionThread-28]   - Thread Name is: SessionThread-28
2020-03-02 04:25:51,704 INFO  [SessionThread-25]   - Thread Name is: SessionThread-25
2020-03-02 04:25:51,704 INFO  [SessionThread-23]   - Thread Name is: SessionThread-23
2020-03-02 04:25:51,709 INFO  [SessionThread-20]   - Thread Name is: SessionThread-20
2020-03-02 04:25:51,709 INFO  [SessionThread-7]   - Thread Name is: SessionThread-7
2020-03-02 04:25:51,709 INFO  [SessionThread-15]   - Thread Name is: SessionThread-15
2020-03-02 04:25:51,714 INFO  [SessionThread-17]   - Thread Name is: SessionThread-17
2020-03-02 04:25:51,714 INFO  [SessionThread-27]   - Thread Name is: SessionThread-27
2020-03-02 04:25:51,719 INFO  [SessionThread-14]   - Thread Name is: SessionThread-14
2020-03-02 04:25:51,724 INFO  [SessionThread-26]   - Thread Name is: SessionThread-26
2020-03-02 04:25:51,724 INFO  [SessionThread-24]   - Thread Name is: SessionThread-24
2020-03-02 04:25:51,739 INFO  [SessionThread-13]   - Thread Name is: SessionThread-13
2020-03-02 04:25:51,744 INFO  [SessionThread-18]   - Thread Name is: SessionThread-18
2020-03-02 04:25:51,744 INFO  [SessionThread-19]   - Thread Name is: SessionThread-19
2020-03-02 04:25:51,769 INFO  [SessionThread-22]   - Thread Name is: SessionThread-22
```

Comment: Where is your SessionThread implementation? In your execute() method you are creating each thread for each file and starting the thread so that for every file new thread will create. You can use run() method instead of start() from your sessionThread so that the job will be executed by your ExecutorService thread pool.

Comment: SessionThread is specific to the application/tool we use. We don't have code for SessionThread. However, it implements the java Thread class. 

Will it create new threads if I call run?

executor.execute(() -> new SessionThread(new FileList(file), session).run());

Comment: Why? Your disk isn't multithreaded. You would almost certainly be as well off reading them sequentlally.

Comment: @user207421 - Do you mean if I call run then would be reading sequentially?

Comment: @PKJ You can just pass the instance of SessionThread to the execute() method. The execute() method in ExecutorService expects an instance of Runnable. Since SessionThread is a Runnable type you can pass it as an argument. The creation and execution of those tasks will be taken care of by your executor service.

Comment: @JinuPC Yup. That's what I did. Thanks!